# Integrating over an interpolate function (interp1d) in python

Tags: python, function, integration, interpolation, iterable

I am trying to do double integration over an interpolated function, in which `r = r(x,y)`.

```
from scipy import interpolate
import scipy as sp

r = [0, 1, 2]
z = [0, 1, 2]

def cartesian(x, y, f):
    r = sp.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    return f(r)

interp = interpolate.interp1d(r, z)

print(cart(1,1,interp))

a = sp.integrate.dblquad(cart, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1, args=(interp))
print(a)
```

Executing the Cartesian function once produces the correct answer. However the integral gives the the following error:

```
TypeError: integrate() argument after * must be an iterable, not interp1d
```

I don't understand why my function isn't `iterable` and do not know how to convert it into an `iterable` form. Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is supposed to be a *sequence* of arguments, so:

```
sp.integrate.dblquad(cart, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1, args=(interp,))
```

The comma after `interp` is critical: in Python, `(x)` is just `x`, but `(x,)` is a tuple (i.e. a sequence).